# Google Auth Code Flow requesting token generates invalid client error when exchanging ID token for Access Token

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Fairly new in looking at the Google OAuth library, but have spent a while in Azure/Exchange OAuth.
We have a wrapper around the various libraries in the Adapter Pattern, so our app code is consistent and calls the same methods. Here's what the Google one looks like

```
private string _state;
private GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow _flow;

public GoogleTokenProvider(IOAuthSettings settings, string state, string baseUrl) : base(settings, state, baseUrl)
{
    //https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc
    _state = state;
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer init = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = settings.ClientId,
            ClientSecret = settings.ClientSecret
        },
        Scopes = this.Scopes,
        DataStore = new GoogleTokenStore(settings) //Our implementation - not called yet
    };
    _flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(init);
}
```

The first step (once constructed) is to get the url to start the auth process.

```
public string GetAuthorizationUrl()
{
    //Using Flow 
    var req = _flow.CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(this.RedirectUrl);
    var baseUrl = req.Build().AbsoluteUri;
    baseUrl += "&state=" + this._state;
    return baseUrl;

    // Manually build request
    //StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    //builder.Append("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?");
    //builder.AppendFormat("scope={0}", String.Join("+", this.Scopes));
    //builder.Append("&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code");
    //builder.AppendFormat("&state={0}&", this._state);
    //builder.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", this.RedirectUrl);
    //builder.AppendFormat("&client_id={0}", this.settings.ClientId);
    //return builder.ToString();
}
```

This works, and we're directed off to the OAuth site, we log in with our Google account. Our callback is fired and when debugging the callback, we obtain the code, and state passed through and call this method:

```
public string AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(string code)
{
    Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse result = _flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("userid", code, RedirectUrl, new System.Threading.CancellationToken()).Result;
    return result.AccessToken;
}
```

However, this causes an error:
[image: Error details]

`Error:"invalid_client", Description:"Unauthorized", Uri:""`

There are two queries.

1. I am unsure what "UserId" should be, a lot of posts just have "userid" or "me" in there, so what it is for?
2. Since the Flow class is built by the same settings, why does the client suddenly become invalid.

Thanks in advance.

## Google Configuration

[image: Google Web Client created]

The intent is to be able to read the emails (Gmail) from this account

Enabled APIs:

- Gmail API
- Google+ API

### google Data Store Implementation

```
public class GoogleTokenStore : IDataStore
{
    private readonly IOAuthSettings _settings;
    public GoogleTokenStore(IOAuthSettings settings)
    {
        this._settings = settings;
    }
    private Dictionary<string, T> Decode<T>()
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            
            memoryStream.Write(_settings.TokenStore, 0, _settings.TokenStore.Length);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream) as Dictionary<string, T>;
        }
    }

    private void Encode<T>(Dictionary<string, T> store)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, store);
            _settings.TokenStore = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

    public Task ClearAsync()
    {
        _settings.TokenStore = null;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task DeleteAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        if (_settings.TokenStore == null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask; //THIS IS CALLED, RETURNS HERE
        }
        var store = Decode<T>();
        if (store.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            store.Remove(key);
            Encode<T>(store);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string key)
    {
        var store = Decode<T>();
        if (store.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return Task.FromResult( store[key] );
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Task StoreAsync<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        var store = Decode<T>();
        if(store != null)
        {
            store.Add(key, value);
            Encode<T>(store);
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Stack trace of the Google error

```
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse.<FromHttpResponseAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.<ExecuteAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<FetchTokenAsync>d__35.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.<ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync>d__30.MoveNext()
```

I have included this code as it does appear the Delete was called  and on returning Task.CompletedTask the error appears (on initial call the store is null so just return Task.CompletedTask

Answer (score 0):

Invalid_client error normally means that you have created one type of client on Google Developer console and are using the code for a different type of client.

There are two types of clients normally used with .net applications Desktop app, and web browser client.    The code used for them is different.  You are appear to be using the MCV code.  I would double check that you have created a web browser client on Google developer console.

## update from comments

If you check the documentation
[MVC](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-mvc)

Check the section for AppFlowMetadata

You are going to have a problem because its looking for a session var on each users browser

```
var user = controller.Session["user"];
```

It uses that session var to know which users data to load from

```
DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
```

So if you want to make this single user make sure to always set the session var to that of the user whos data you want to load.  check %appData% its where file data store default stores its credential files for each user.   [Check this if your curios what IDataStore is](https://www.daimto.com/google-net-filedatastore-demystified/)

Comment: Hi DalmTo - I updated the question with some information on the Google setup, let me know if more is helpful. It appears to be set as a Web Client. The intent is to use this token to check emails on the account and process them, so it is a one time authentication and then re-use the token/refresh after that.

Comment: I didn't know the MVC could would let you pass it a refresh token in that manner.  Can you also post the code where you are storing the refresh token for later use,  I assumed it stored it in session cookies.  If its one time authorization you could technically just use the installed application code and then upload the refresh token along with your project as an env var or something.

Comment: Well, that may well be my next question then! Maybe I am going down a wrong path. I have not written code to do the refresh yet, I am doing the initial authentication. I get the consent screen, jump through all the Google hoops, and then hit the redirectUrl callback. I have a code provided, I then try and exchange that code for an access token and get the error. Is there a better flow/process?

Comment: The thing is that the Client library is designed to handle all the refreshing for you. YOu shouldn't be doing any of this you should let the library handel it.   The thing is every user that wants to see that page is going to need to jump though all those authorization hoops.  Authorization is user based, each user will need to be authorized.

Comment: Only the system admin will see it, they will authenticate email boxes which the application will then read from every 5-10 minutes. I did start manually creating the requests (commented out code) but moved to use the client lib. The lib creates the request url, we go there, we authenticate, we return and it is exchanging the code for a token which is erroring. I hope the lib will auto refresh etc when asking for a token, just not got that far yet.

Comment: Check my update.  Im pretty sure we can get it working for you with the library i just haven't touched the MVC stuff in like five years, we may need to play with it a little.

Comment: I had some help with the library from Google, the jury is still out on one issue, which I wondered if you had an opinion. If I authenticate my client mailbox with Google, it works, if I then auth SMTP with it, same clientID, I don't get a refresh token back. In fact, until I revoke in Google, no refresh token comes back when I setup any new account (say deleted the existing) in the app. Assume google knew it was done once, but this seems a flaw.